# R: tibble move columns to row & name columns

Tags: r, transpose, tibble

I have a clean tibble, as shown below:

```
df <- structure(list(created_week = c(31, 32, 33, 34), Rt_count = c(7, 
6, 5, 0), Cus_count = c(2, 1, 2, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .Names = c("created_week", "Rt_count", "Cus_count"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I am looking at doing same as t() from base, with a tibble as result and  row from df$created_week with their name, columns are Rt_count and Cus_count and must be named.
I can't find a simple and easy way.

Thank you for help.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. If Rt_count & Cus_count remain columns, is that transposing the data frame? Or do you simply want to convert the first column to row names? For the latter, check out `tibble::column_to_rownames`

Comment: @Z.Lin column_to_rownames(tt, var = "toto")
Error: Column `num2` not found

Comment: You have to specify which column to convert to rowname. Try `df %>% column_to_rownames("created_week") %>% as.data.frame()`?

Comment: @Z.Lin exactly what I want. TY. Can you answer the question? There is a warning still: Warning message:
Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reposting my comment as answer...

In order to create rownames from df$created_week while leaving Rt_count & Cus_count as columns, you can use the `column_to_rownames` function from the `tibble` package.

You'll get a warning that setting row names on a tibble is deprecated, but that's fine since we'll convert it back to data.frame:

```
library(dplyr); library(tibble)

df %>% 
  column_to_rownames("created_week") %>% 
  as.data.frame()

   Rt_count Cus_count
31        7         2
32        6         1
33        5         2
34        0         1
```

**Edit** for alternative that doesn't depend on `tibble`'s function:

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
rownames(df) <- df$created_week
df$created_week <- NULL
```

Comment: I just want to add this will be depreciated. See https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/123 for more info

Comment: Darn, I just learned the function a month ago. All right, will include an alternative using only base packages...